# can I change laptop bios menu hotkey?

Tags: windows-7, bios, hotkeys, toshiba-laptop

I am trying to update the Toshiba Satellite c665 from windows 7 to 10 using bootable USB, but all my hotkey (f2,f12, ESC) is not working, so is there any way to change the hotkey or any method to install new windows using USB?

Comment: According to [the manual](https://cdn.cnetcontent.com/40/45/404552d5-ea14-4fba-8d3c-8279e65f1aac.pdf), you should be able to "1. Hold down F12 and boot the computer. when the TOSHIBA Leading Innovation >>> screen appears, release the F12 key. 2. Use the up and down cursor keys to select the boot device you want and press ENTER."

Comment: Install Ubuntu, which allows BIOS access directly from the GRUB2 boot menu. You might find the old CPU too slow for Windows 10, anyway.

Comment: Please test your keyboard to see if F2 and F12 are working: you can use a program like [Keyboard Tester](https://sourceforge.net/projects/keyboardtester/).

Comment: The manual also says there is a Toshiba program you can run to change the boot device. I imagine you might be able to end up with an unbootable system if you didn't read the instructions carefully ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton according to the manual it says we can overwrite the selected boot device by clicking some specified key while the device is booting up, so I choose S for USB memory according to the manual but nothing registers. It directly opens windows boot managers as before. Is there any way to run bootable USB using cmd, because I can access advanced boot options and therefore command prompt.

Comment: @kshitizghimire I don't want you to end up with an unbootable system, but if you look in "Chapter 7: HW Setup" in the manual, it seems to say that you can press S while the system is booting to boot from a USB drive.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I already did that, but nothing registers and directly opens windows boot manager as before. And also I can't see USB as boot pirority in HW Setup software.

Comment: @kshitizghimire Oops, somehow I missed that you'd already tried pressing S. That does make me wonder if perhaps the laptop needs a BIOS update, but it looks like you would need to find a Windows BIOS updater program from Toshiba, if such a thing exists. You can find the current version from with Windows by entering `wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion` at a command prompt.

Comment: @kshitizghimire Do you have an external USB DVD drive? Or maybe you could borrow one? If you have the option to boot from that, it could be the way to go.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The latest version found is 1.30 
ACPI Flash BIOS version 1.30 for Satellite (Pro) C645/C655 (PSC2Ex/Fx/Gx/Sx/Tx/Wx)
but my pc model number is C665 and bios version is 1.30, since the version is same it throws an error while installing, saying the version of ROM file is the same as that of BIOS. Should I downgrade the version to 1.20 .

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't have external USB DVD.

Comment: @kshitizghimire I don't think that downgrading the BIOS version will help.

Comment: @AndrewMorton so the only solution is, either to use an external USB DVD or to fix the keyboard, right?

Comment: @kshitizghimire What did you use to check if the F2 key works in Windows? Also, I can't imagine that the S key is not working. So, it is very unlikely to be a keyboard problem. Are you *sure* that you're spamming the F2 key as soon as you've pressed the power button, and keep on spamming it? Some laptops are fussy about the time interval during which the F2 key needs to be pressed. If it gets to the Windows boot manager, it's too late.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I used https://keyboardchecker.com/ website to check keys. And the S key works fine, but while pressing/spamming a second after the power button has been pressed it registers nothing.

Comment: @kshitizghimire I just had a thought: does your laptop have an internal DVD drive? You can burn the Windows 10 installer to a DVD: [Create installation media for Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d). Then use the HW Setup program to set it to boot from that. Actually, before burning a disc, you could try inserting any DVD and see if will try to boot from it: it might fail and tell you to insert a bootable disk, and at that point you might find some way to get into the BIOS.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have, but its broken, I will fix it and try this DVD method. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the key. Those Bios keys are almost always hardcoded in the Bios and can (in general) not be changed without replacing the Bios with a hacked version. (Not something the average computer user can/should do.)

It should be F2 on your laptop.

If the laptop boots to quick for you to press the key at the right moment just press the F2 key down while the laptop is OFF and then turn it on while keeping the F2 pressed down. You might get an error-message but it should get you in the bios so you can change the boot-order so that the USB-stick is the first boot-device.

Please note: An external keyboard attached to the laptop will in most cases NOT work for this. You need to use the laptops internal keyboard.

Comment: in my case all f2,esc and f12 is not working, what can I do now so I may be able to update new windows.

Comment: I also used software like keytweak to remap the f2 key with another key, but still it didn't work.

Comment: @kshitizghimire It wont work.  BIOS loads before the OS, which is where you made the change.

Comment: understood, do I have to change my keyboard or is there another way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.  Is BIOS asking you to hit a *specific* key and its not working to go into BIOS?  If so, is the key actually broken?  Does the key work in Windows?

If the keys are actually broken on the keyboard on your laptop, you can use an external USB keyboard.  Just plug it in, boot the laptop, and hit the required BIOS key.  However, you should look into replacing the keyboard on the laptop.

Comment: no while booting up laptop the first things appear in laptop is windows boot manager. if I click f2 or f12 while windows is booting up nothing changes also those keys does not work in windows too.

Comment: theres no splash screen when you turn on the laptop?

Comment: the 1st things I see after I press power button is Windows Boot Manager, which says choose an operating system to start, or press Tab to select a tool: where I can choose windows 7 or windows fast mode.
in Tools: there is Windows Memory diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you fully shutdown the computer before trying to enter the BIOS.

Download and install the
[Toshiba HW Setup Utility](https://support.dynabook.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=3410336).

If you do not have the HWSetup tool, go to the Toshiba support site
and enter your serial number. You can download the one for your
machine from there.

In the application,
ensure that in the General tab for the HDD the Boot Speed is set to Normal.
This might give you more time to spam the BIOS key that is displayed
during the boot.

[image]

If this doesn't help, HWSetup might have an option for changing
the boot key.

Comment: under boot priority options I could not find USB. but I have enabled it from top nav bar.